# Below Sql query is taking too much time. How to make this faster?

Tags: mysql, performance, query-optimization

```
SELECT 
 call_id
,call_date
,call_no
,call_amountdue
,rechargesamount
,call_penalty
,callpayment_received
,calldiscount
FROM `call`
WHERE calltype = 'Regular' 
AND callcode = 98 
AND call_connect = 1 
AND call_date < '2018-01-01'
ORDER BY 
 `call_date` DESC
,`call_id` DESC
limit 1
```

Index is already there on call_date, callcode, calltype, callconnect

Table has 10 million records. Query is taking 2 min

How to get results within 3sec?

Comment: I formatted your query for readability.  The question appears to be carelessly written (column names don't match between query and index, missing spaces).   Some of the columns look like low cardinality so indexes are probably don't doing much for you.  Are those individual indices or a single multi column index?  What have you done so far?  What's your query plan?

Comment: individual indices.i tried with composite index also but result is same

Comment: You could try a covering multi-column index (call_data, calltype, callcode, call_connect, call_data).  Also, try adding call_id as the second column followed by the rest in the index. The problem is probably that `call_date < '2018-01-01`` may be a significant chunk of your table, then you have so short that to find a single row.  If you could add a lower bound, say, call_date >= '2017-01-01' that might cut down the number of rows you look at.  Anyways, post output of explain of the query, so I am just guessing here.

Comment: Show EXPLAIN for the query. *Index is already there on call_date,callcode,calltype,callconnect* Test - move `call_date` to the end of the index expressoin.

Comment: @Akina I think you want to it first to take advantage of it being sorted, no?

Comment: calltype = 'Regular' have 5 million records it self

Comment: @AllanWind I think that the query will use filesort anycase. And I move the condition by uneqiation last because this condition should be performed by indexscan ("using where").

Answer (score 0):

```
INDEX (calltype, callcode, call_connect,   -- in any order
       call_date,     -- next
       call_id)       -- last
```

This will make it possible to find the one row that is desired without having to step over other rows.

Since you seem to have `INDEX(calltype)`, Drop it; it will be in the way and, anyway, redundant.  The rest of the indexes you mentioned will be ignored.

More discussion in [*Index Cookbook*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql)